# .net remoting, How to reconnect if the connect is lost?

Tags: c#, .net-remoting

I have this working but i don't understand how to predict when the connection has dropped and needs to reconnect to the server.

what i want to do is have the client connect right away to the .net remoting server if it drops out, sort of like keep trying to connect and disregard if it does not need to.

help appreciated.

here is my code:

```
namespace TaskClient
{
    using System;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
    using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp;
    using System.Threading;
    using TaskShared;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpChannel chan = new TcpChannel();
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan, false);
            Connections remObject = (Connections)Activator.GetObject(typeof(Connections), "tcp://localhost:8085/TaskServer");

            if (remObject == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to TaskServer. (tcp://localhost:8085/TaskServer)");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to Task Server.");

                var rt = new TestTask() 
                {
                    ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
                    ComputerName = Environment.MachineName,
                    VersionInfo = "1.0.0",
                    JobRunning = "None"
                };

                remObject.Add(rt);
            }


            while (true)
            {
                //TODO:
                //Check if connected.. how?
                //Re-create the connection... how?

                //doing this simple won't work:
                if (remObject == null)
                    remObject = (Connections)Activator.GetObject(typeof(Connections), "tcp://localhost:8085/TaskServer");



                remObject.Invalidate(remObject[rt]);

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you have a heartbeat sent to/from your server every (X) seconds/milliseconds from/to the connected client(s). If the connected client hasn't received it's heartbeat after a period of time you restart your connection process, or have your Client send it to the server.